# Shorten this code to check for null in expression

Tags: kotlin

I have this code:

```
if ((oldTest != null) && (oldTest.snapshotUrl != null)) {
    val startPos = oldTest.snapshotUrl!!.lastIndexOf("_") + 1
}
```

Is there a way in Kotlin to shorten this? I don't believe it's necessary to check to see if oldTest.snapshotUrl is null. Unfortunately this does not work:

```
if (oldTest != null) {
    val startPos = oldTest.snapshotUrl?.lastIndexOf("_") + 1
}
```

Comment: Please, when something "does not work", be more explicit: say what you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely.

Comment: If the code you are running has a smaller scope and returning is meaningful, you can also do `oldTest ?: return`, which means that if this is `null` return. If it's not null then the oldTest is automatically cast as `non-null`, effectively reducing the null check to just one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
oldTest?.snapshotUrl?.let {
  val startPos = it.lastIndexOf("_") + 1
}
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null

Or, if `snapshotUrl` is not nullable

```
oldTest?.let {
  val startPos = it.snapshotUrl.lastIndexOf("_") + 1
}
```